# Definite integral $\int_2^{343} ({x-[x]})^2 dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

$$ I = \int_2^{343} ({x-[x]})^2 dx $$

Actually , I m stuck in the question of definite integral ,

I know that
  $x-[x]$ is $\{x\}$ which is fractional part of function , but unable to proceed further. Please help.

Comment: Do you mean $$ I = \int_2^{343} (x-[x])^ 2 dx ?$$

Comment: Yes, I'm dealing with little difficulty in posting the question. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ is periodic.

Comment: There is a momentary temptation to try to answer a question like this by just explaining how to evaluate the integral. But a deeper problem than inability to know what to do with the integral is here. I think a frequent reason why students have trouble with problems of this kind is that they begin by asking themselves which among the techniques they have been taught should be used here. That's the wrong thing to do first. Approaching it that way will result in only knowing how to do what you've been shown how to do. As if you knew how to drive a car only to places that$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$someone has shown you how to drive to. The first thing to do, before asking yourself which techniques you have been taught should be used, is to work on understanding the question. And when posting here, say something about what you have understood and specifically where your difficulty is. The lack of specificity about where the difficulty is, is probably the reason why some have voted to close the question. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

$I=\sum_{k=2}^{342} \int_{k}^{k+1} (x-k)^2dx=\sum_{k=2}^{342}\frac{1}{3}=\frac{341}{3}$

Comment: Can u Please explain it .

Comment: You just use the fact that between two consecutive integers $[x]$ is constant. What is unclear?

Comment: Yes , I got that , thanks .

Answer (score 2):

When you are struggling with an integral, it can often help to make a graph of the integrand. (WolframAlpha: [graph of $x-\lfloor x \rfloor$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x+-+floor(x)) and [graph of $(x-\lfloor x \rfloor)^2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+(x+-+floor(x))%5E2). In this case, a graph makes it easy to see that the value of the integral is just 341 times the value of $\int_0^1{x^2}\,dx$, or $341\times \frac{1}{3}$.

To prove it, first show that the integrand $f(x) = (x - [x])^2$ satisfies $f(x+n) = f(x)$ when $n$ is an integer: $$f(x+n) = (x + n - [x + n])^2 =  (x + n - ([x] + n))^2 = (x - [x])^2 = f(x)\,.$$ Next express the integral as a sum of integrals
$$\int_2^{343}{f(x)\,dx} = \int_2^{3}{f(x)\,dx} + \int_3^{4}{f(x)\,dx} + \dots + \int_{342}^{343}{f(x)\,dx} = \sum_{n=2}^{342}{\int_n^{n+1}{f(x)\,dx}}\,.$$
In the rightmost integral, the substitution $u = x - n$ gives
$$\sum_{n=2}^{342}{\int_0^{1}{f(u+n)\,du}}\,.$$
Using the property $f(u+n) = f(u)$ derived earlier, this is
$$\sum_{n=2}^{342}{\int_0^{1}{f(u)\,du}}\,.$$
But in the interval $[0, 1]$, we have $f(u) = (u - [u])^2 = (u - 0)^2 = u^2$. So the integral is
$$\sum_{n=2}^{342}{\int_0^{1}{u^2\,du}} = \sum_{n=2}^{342}{\frac{1}{3}} = 341\times\frac{1}{3}\,.$$

Comment: I think that if an answer relies heavily on the graph, perhaps it would be good to include graph into the post. (I have at least added link to WA, but including a picture would probably be nicer.) Of course, I cannot say whether this is the main reason why this answer was downvoted.